# Cannot get loadkeys to change key mappings

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

The man page for keymaps(5) includes this quote:

> Here's an example to bind the string "du\ndf\n" to the key AltGr-D. We
>   use the "spare" action  code  F100  not normally bound to any key.

```
altgr keycode 32 = F100
string F100 = "du\ndf\n"
```

I created a file and copy & pasted those two lines, then ran

```
sudo loadkeys new_keymap
```

It completed without error, but AltGr-D still (either in Terminal or in LO Writer) printed the same character as before (an accented ‘o’).

What am I doing wrong?

**What I’m really trying to do**

I have a keyboard with some extra keys. The Mail key opens or restores my email client, Thunderbird – brilliant! I did nothing to configure this key, it worked immediately after I installed Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon.

The My Documents key does not work, nothing happens when it is pressed. I would like it to open the file manager (more precisely, to run the command `nemo ~/Documents` in Cinnamon).

`showkey` reports that Mail is scan code 155, and My Documents is 235.

Having found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4200836/8557840
I created a keymap file containing

```
keycode 88 = F12
string F12 = "nemo "
```

but that does not change F12.

Changing the scan code to 235 does not affect the My Documents key.

I need to configure the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JdeBP gave references that are very technical. After lots of reading, I found an easy way.

Menu→Preferences→Keyboard→Shortcuts→Custom Shortcuts→Add custom shortcut

There's a reference here: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-the-linux-mint-cinnamon-keyboard-shortcuts-4064754

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are erroneously expecting the keyboard map that is applied by the `loadkeys` program to the built-in terminal emulator in the kernel that handles kernel virtual terminals, to apply to X11 programs.  You are configuring the wrong keyboard mapping.  Configure your XKB mappings.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480705/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326804/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479720/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181367/5132

Comment: Thank you for pointing out where I am going wrong.